# Where does boost::make_shared size of memory allocation for underlying object and reference counting object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-ptr, make-shared

I am trying to understand how `boost::make_shared` does the memory allocation for the object managed by a `boost::shared_ptr` and the reference-counting object (the `shared_ptr` uses) together.

The `make_shared` function begins execution here:

```
template< class T, class A1, class A2, class A3 >
typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array< T >::type make_shared( A1 && a1, A2 && a2, A3 && a3 )
{
    //Seems to create the smart_ptr for the object
    boost::shared_ptr< T > pt( static_cast< T* >( 0 ), BOOST_SP_MSD( T ) );

    //Not sure?
    boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter< T > * pd = static_cast<boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter< T > *>( pt._internal_get_untyped_deleter() );

    //Calculates the address at which the bulk-allocation begins
    void * pv = pd->address();

    //Allocates the memory at address pv?
    ::new( pv ) T(
        boost::detail::sp_forward<A1>( a1 ), 
        boost::detail::sp_forward<A2>( a2 ), 
        boost::detail::sp_forward<A3>( a3 )
        );

    //Not sure
    pd->set_initialized();

    //Not sure
    T * pt2 = static_cast< T* >( pv );

    //Not sure
    boost::detail::sp_enable_shared_from_this( &pt, pt2, pt2 );
    return boost::shared_ptr< T >( pt, pt2 );
}
```

Would somebody be able to help explain the remaining lines?

I am trying to identify where the size of the bulk memory allocation (the object being pointed to **and** the shared_ptr reference counting object) is determined?

What's throwing me is that the call to `address()` doesn't seem to consider the size of the `T` object when allocating the address to allocate at.

(I really don't get what the three `AX` parameters are which enter the method and are passed to the placement `new()` call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take it line by line

```
  boost::shared_ptr< T > pt( static_cast< T* >( 0 ), BOOST_SP_MSD( T ) );
```

This creates the shared pointer, but the key here is the deleter.  The `BOOST_SP_MSD(T)` is a macro which resolves to a deleter with enough extra space for your data.  So the shared pointer reference count block also includes the space for the deleter, which now includes the space for your T

```
    //Not sure?
    boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter< T > * pd = static_cast<boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter< T > *>( pt._internal_get_untyped_deleter() );
```

This gets the deleter address from the shared pointer. This will point to the deleter created above.

```
    //Calculates the address at which the bulk-allocation begins
    void * pv = pd->address();
```

This returns the starting address of for the type `T`, which is currently uninitialized and is part of the deleter

```
    //Allocates the memory at address pv?
    ::new( pv ) T(
        boost::detail::sp_forward<A1>( a1 ), 
        boost::detail::sp_forward<A2>( a2 ), 
        boost::detail::sp_forward<A3>( a3 )
        );
```

This is a placement-new.  This constructs your `T` at the address provided in `pv`.  It's passing 3 arguments because this is the 3-arg version of `make_shared`.

```
    //Not sure
    pd->set_initialized();
```

This is an internal flag in the deleter, which lets it know that the `T` has been constructed (so that when the deleter's `operator()` is called, it will destroy it)

```
    //Not sure
    T * pt2 = static_cast< T* >( pv );
```

This casts the void* above into the `T*`.  Honestly, I'm not sure why they just didn't retain the result of the placement new.

```
    //Not sure
    boost::detail::sp_enable_shared_from_this( &pt, pt2, pt2 );
```

This is necessary to provide the `enable_shared_from_this` functionality.   This internal function sets up the underlying mechanism for `enable_shared_from_this`.  It's normally called when you place something into the `shared_ptr`

```
    return boost::shared_ptr< T >( pt, pt2 );
```

This actually creates a new `boost::shared_ptr` that uses the same reference counted region as the `pt`, but its `get()` and related methods will return `pt2`, which is the pointer to `T`, which is stored in the deleter.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking the reference counting object is placed before the object in memory, with a lower address?

Comment: @user997112: I don't know, but I would guess yes.  Relying on any particular placement seems unwise.

Comment: Indeed, more so since the placement will likely be different if you do `shared_ptr<T>(new T)` vs. `make_shared<T>()`. It's an implementation detail and the standard doesn't say anything about it.